# Shared Files - Can't find Solution for new Android 10 Scoped Storage restrictions?

Tags: android

We have a suite of applications that depend on the sharing of a directory/files on external storage.
I've currently opted out of the Android 10 OS changes to scoping (requestLegacyExternalStorage), but this is going away and I've spent many hours trying to find a solution for simply sharing files between applications.

The only solutions that I see offered are:

- SAF - which appears to make the user choose through UI.  This is completely undesirable.
- Use a File Content Provider - the way I understand this, I would have to make the user install an apk with my provider in it before installing any of my applications.  Forcing the user to install two apks to run one application is very undesirable.  (Yes, they could both be in one apk manifest but who knows which of my suite they will want to install)
- Media Store - My understanding is that this also forces the user to pick something he should have no knowledge of - and is really intended for audio, video, image and downloaded directory.

Am I missing a solution for these simple requirements?

Comment: `Media Store - My understanding is that this also forces the user to pick something he should have no knowledge of `. A user should know about all. Nobody asked for a MediaStore . But users do know about files on an sd card and should know about it. So let them choose a place with saf. Or use the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing a solution for these simple requirements?

There is no simple solution. You would basically need to have each app have its own copy of the shared data (to deal with potential uninstalls) and have some sort of synchronization protocol so each app in the suite can inform others about changes to their copy of the data.

Using SAF is the simplest approach for your scenario. Or, move the data off the device into "the cloud".

> My understanding is that this also forces the user to pick something he should have no knowledge of

It is the user's device. It is the user's storage. If you put files in a user-visible location on the user's storage, **they are the user's files**. Your apps are merely one set of tools for working with those files, nothing more.

Comment: I understand it's the user's device, so every file is technically the user's.  But these are technical device-level config files that need to be shared between my applications and used to be invisible to the user.  This would require unnecessary user education to make sure the file and the location of the file was chosen properly (and the same for each running of each app).  It's would make a very poor user experience that inevitably would cause issues, and up until this point has been completely unnecessary.  Synching to the cloud would require a "device service" be created...

Comment: @leewill: "and used to be invisible to the user" -- if they were on external storage, they were not invisible to the user. The point of external storage is for files to be visible to the user.

Comment: I have no need to argue a tedious point.  I know my users would rather not know about this file.  Just looking for a way to keep my two requirements of simple installation and continued invisibility (albeit pseudo).